# net of a solid church-like

Tags: geometry

[image: church]
[image: answer]

What is the correct net for the solid ? It is a multiple choice.
It may be the red one.

What is the systematic way to find the solution ?
I imagined the net folded, and what should I check ? I mean for nets of cuboid,I check that the opposite faces are isometric, I check that adjacent vertices have the same length. What is the method here ?

Comment: Isn't this multiple choice?

Comment: It is a multiple choice indeed.

Comment: Why church-like and not plainly house-like ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Houses in many locations are not usually shaped like that.

Comment: @Oussema ... neither churches... More seriously see the nice illustration [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1732367) with the essential concept of "**spanning tree**".

Comment: @JeanMarie Good point.

Comment: Figure 1 and 3 are both correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to imagine the net folded.

If you're unable to do that, then checking relationships between adjacent edges will at least allow you to rule out Figure 4, but that's definitely not enough.

Instead, try to imagine unfolding the solid into a net. Which of Figures 1, 2, and 3 can you obtain?

As a hint, one of them is a trick, and relies on a segment-length equality that does not match your figure.

Comment: It is the red one, indeed. I checked again.

Comment: It is, indeed! Well done. :-)

Comment: Thanks, instead of folding each net, I unfolded the solid.

Comment: I commented above that it's a multiple choice question. How did I know that?

Comment: @WhatsUp: I suspect that you knew that based on the presentation of the post.

Comment: @CameronBuie I knew that because I saw two correct options.

Comment: Figure 1 and 3 are both correct.

Comment: @WhatsUp: It only seems as if those are both correct, but relative length matters.

Comment: @Seyed: It only seems as if those are both correct, but relative length matters.

Comment: @CameronBuie, since there is no measurement on the figures it is not easy to tell by just looking at them.